# iOS + C: the use of __attribute__ ((__constructor__)) in static framework

Tags: ios, c, clang, llvm-clang

I did quite a bit of googling for a definitive answer, but I could not find one.

We have cross-platform sources that need to be used by our iOS apps.  I have already packaged them as static framework and got a test app to link successfully against and make a call into it.

The problem I am having is that it makes heavy use of global static constructors.

I am seeing erratic behavior with only a subset of objects getting instantiated but not all.

My questions:

1. Do static constructors even work within the context of an iOS static
   lib?
2. How would one debug such a problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. constructors in a static library get called erratically
2. The use of -all_load and -force_load does not make any difference in invocation of **constructor** attribute labeled functions
3. What you need to do is this:

   - make sure the constructors are global symbols.  do this by exporting them via a symbols' file.
   - consider creating an init function and use the linker setting "initialization routine" to control the order of the instantiation of your global objects..

Answer (score 0):

> Do static constructors work within the context of an iOS static lib?

They only start to work once they're linked into an executable, but once that is accomplished they will work.

> How do you debug such a problem

There are a few approaches

- You have to presume no specific order of the invocation of the constructors.
- Make sure the constructors are being linked into the executable (use nm to determine this)
- You can try an `-Wl,-all_load` to get it to load all the components of all archives into the executable (or `-Wl,-force_load,libstatic.a` to just load for a specific static archive).

Comment: do these flags (-Wl,-all_load & -Wl,-force_load) get passed as part of the static library build or as part of the app build that links against the static lib?  Also, i nm'ed the framework and saw erratic symbol values for objects that get instantiated thru the very same macro'ed function: (1) all symbols exist as 't' [non-external] (2) some have address/offset values; others have 00000000 as their address/offset.

Comment: logically the flags should probably be used within the app's project.  i'll give it a shot and update.

Comment: -all_load and -force_load did not make any difference.